# What is the alternative of the combination of two pattern matching conditions?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

So what i want to do is to search in my table `data` for elements that in their name exists the word `first` and the word `second`. These two words can be seperated or attached to each others. A translation of that would be the following :

```
SELECT name FROM data WHERE name ILIKE '%first%' AND name ILIKE '%second%'
```

I searched a bit for an alternative for this query and how i can combine the condition in a regular expression but no luck.

My concern is performance problems if this query were to be performed over a large table. I already created the following index (which sped up considerably the search) :

```
CREATE INDEX pattern_matching_index ON data USING GIN (name gin_trgm_ops);
```

Is there a better way to perform this kind of search ? or is this as good as it's going to get ?

Comment: With that index it should just work.  What problems did you encounter?  Is it still too slow?  Do you not like the way it treats word boundaries?

Comment: if the order of frist and second in the target known? is it known that the two strings do not overlap?

Comment: @Colin'tHart i updated the post with the version tag.
@jjanes until now i didn't encounter any problems with it, but it seemed to me just not logical that there is no support for `&` and we need to write the condition over and over again, in my case, users can look for something that demand writing this condition 100+ times.
@Jasen the order is known but it's not know that the two strings do not overlap.

Comment: I don't see a difference between writing `name ILIKE ... AND` over and over again, versus writing `.*` over and over again (which wouldn't work anyway if they can overlap).  Either way it will probably be done in software, not by hand.  I don't understand what you mean by `&`, is that supposed to be an SQL operator or a regexp operator, or a tsquery operator?

Comment: i meant with it as a wildcard, i expected that the following is possible : `WHERE name ILIKE '%first&second%'` which translates to `WHERE name ILIKE '%first%' AND name ILIKE '%second%'`. It's true that it's going to be done by software but i thought the two different writings will behave differently internally which will impact the performance. All of this is just out of speculation.

Answer (score 2):

If `first` and `second` can be any value and could be embedded in other words without any kind of delimiter (eg, `foofirstbar`), then yes, using trigrams is probably as good as you're going to get. If there are a limited number of values for `first` and `second`, you could create an expression index of the name column passed through a `regexp_replace` to add spaces around your target words, and then use the [built-in full-text-search functionality](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-intro.html):

```
testdb=# create table data(t text);
CREATE TABLE
testdb=# insert into data select 'foofirstbarsecondbaz';
INSERT 0 1
testdb=# insert into data select 'foobarsecondbaz';
INSERT 0 1
testdb=# insert into data select 'foosecondbarfirstbaz';
INSERT 0 1
testdb=# select t from data where 'first & second'::tsquery @@ regexp_replace(t, '(first|second)', ' \1 ', 'g')::tsvector;
          t           
----------------------
 foofirstbarsecondbaz
 foosecondbarfirstbaz
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Can you expand your answer to show the difference in execution plans and performance between the two approaches?

Comment: i think this is as good as it's going to get since `first` and `second` can be anything and embeded in other words. Thanks for the alternative anyway